# Changing the cache directory WebStorm

Tags: caching, intellij-idea, webstorm

WebStorm (and I assume IntelliJ), caches a lot of information in a directory called .WebstormXX under the user directory in Windows.

The documentation states that the data is saved here :

```
<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

I would like to ***NOT*** have this data stored here because my network user space is miniscule compared to what is required for the cache directory.

Can I define my .WebstormXX to be for example directly on my C drive?

Answer (score 5):

In `<WebstormLocation>/bin/idea.properties` you can find the properties:

```
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.WebStorm/config
idea.system.path=${user.home}/.WebStorm/system
```

These are commented out by default and are found at the top of `idea.properties`; Uncommenting and redefining them is all you need to do.

Ensure you use forward slashes when defining a new directory.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: should be <WebstormLocation>/bin/idea.properties